# Numpy arange but doubling step size

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently looking for a way to use something similar to `np.arange`, but with the option of doubling the step size.
I know that `np.arange`creates evenly spaced arrays and is not supposed to support variable step sizes.
What I want as an output is something similar to `np.array([0,1,3,7,15,31,...])`.
Is there any built-in function that does this?
I have to use this very often and therefore would prefer to avoid for-loops or similar slow approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```py
2 ** np.arange(0,10,1) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this answer**

Numpy `arange()` function is directly a static step function. We can customize it a little to get the desired array `np.array([0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, ...])`

```
n = 10                     #number of elements
2**np.arange(0, n, 1)-1    #range function
```

This can also provide certain results. This code is much easier than other `for loop` methods.

**Comparing the results**

Using for loops for array creations like this is more efficient in processing than other methods

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(f'np.array([2**i-1 for i in range(10)])', setup='import numpy as np'))
# 3.5182215999811888

print(timeit.timeit(f'np.fromiter((2**i-1 for i in range(10)), int)', setup='import numpy as np'))
# 3.74799029994756

print(timeit.timeit(f'2 ** np.arange(0,10,1) - 1', setup='import numpy as np'))
# 4.791339100105688
```

Hope you found the best answer for you :)

Comment: This depends on your hardware. The pure `numpy` solution is ~1.8x faster (with fairer `np.arange(10)` comparison) than converting a `list comprehension` on a 2-core colab instance.